# Django data table load thousands of rows using server side AJAX

Tags: python, django, ajax, datatable

I have already created a data table that is working just fine. The only problem is that because there are thousands of rows it takes quite a while to load. Below is my code

**view**

```
def live_equity_balance_original(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mt4_checked = 'mt4' in request.POST.getlist('platform')
        mt5_checked = 'mt5' in request.POST.getlist('platform')
        ctrader_checked = 'ctrader' in request.POST.getlist('platform')
        platforms = [var_name for var_name, var_value in [('mt4', mt4_checked), ('mt5', mt5_checked), ('ctr', ctrader_checked)] if var_value]
        variable_names = {
            'mt4': 'balance_equity_mt4_query',
            'mt5': 'balance_equity_mt5_query',
            'ctr': 'balance_equity_ctr_query'
            }

        for platform in platforms:
            if platform in variable_names:
                module_name = 'queries.queries'
                variable_name = variable_names[platform]
                module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
                balance_equity_query = getattr(module, variable_name)
                if platform == 'mt4':
                    df = my_library.get_mt4_data(balance_equity_query)
                    df = df.loc[df.login.astype(str).str.len() > 5]
                    exclude_strings = ['MANAGER','tEsT','COVER']
                    df = df[~df['group'].str.contains('|'.join(exclude_strings),case=False)]
                    df = df.loc[(df['balance']!=0)|(df['equity']!=0)]
                    df = df.head(100)
        headers = df.columns
        json_records = df.reset_index(drop=True).to_json(orient ='records')
        data = json.loads(json_records)
        context = {'headers': headers,'data': data}
        return render(request, 'live_equity_balance.html', context)
```

**table.html template**

```
{% load custom_filters %}
<div class="container">
    <br><br><br>
    <table class="table row-border cell-border display compact" id="example" style="text-align: center;">
        <thead class="table-success">
        <tr>
            {% for header in headers %}
                <th>{{ header }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for item in data %}
        <tr>
            {% for header in headers %}
                <td>{{ item|get_value:header }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.13.4/b-2.3.6/b-html5-2.3.6/datatables.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $('#example').DataTable({
        paging: true,
        pageLength:25,
        lengthChange:true,
        autoWidth:true,
        searching:true,
        bInfo:true,
        bSort:true,
        //buttons
        dom:'lfrtipB',
        language: {
                        lengthMenu: 'Show _MENU_' // Customize the "Show entries" text here
                    },
        buttons:[
            {
            extend: 'csv',
            text:'<i class="fas fa-file-excel">CSV</i>',
            className:'btn btn-secondary',
            titleAttr:'CSV',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    search: 'none'
                }
            }
        }
        ],
        // Adjusted dom option
        initComplete: function () {
            var buttons = $('.dt-buttons').addClass('buttons-container');
            $('.dataTables_length').after(buttons);
        },
    });
    </script>
```

**custom_filters.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_value(item, key):
    return item.get(key, '')
```

I don't know any javascript so I tried a few things that I saw here and there but without much success. I only made it worse. Could you please help?

This is what I have tried so far. It seems that there is no ajax call.
What is being returned is just the response which is a list of dictionaries

**view**

```
        headers = list(df.columns)
        data=[]
        data.extend(df.to_dict(orient='records'))
        response = {'data':data,'headers':headers}
        return JsonResponse(response)
```

**table**

```
 {% load custom_filters %}
<div class="container">
    <br><br><br>
    <table class="table row-border cell-border display compact" id="example" style="text-align: center;">
        <thead class="table-success">
        <tr>
            <th>platform</th>
            <th>login</th>
            <th>balance</th>
            <th>currency</th>
            <th>group</th>
            <th>equity</th>
            <th>leverage</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
            <!--JSON RESPONSE FROM BACKEND-->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-o88AwQnZB+VDvE9tvIXrMQaPlFFSUTR+nldQm1LuPXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.13.4/b-2.3.6/b-html5-2.3.6/datatables.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $('#example').DataTable({
        serverSide: true,
        ajax:"{% url 'live-equity-balance' %}",
        "columns":[
            {"data":"platform"},
            {"data":"login"},
            {"data":"balance"},
            {"data":"currency"},
            {"data":"group"},
            {"data":"equity"},
            {"data":"leverage"}

        ],
        paging: true,
        pageLength:25,
        lengthChange:true,
        autoWidth:true,
        searching:true,
        bInfo:true,
        bSort:true,
        //buttons
        dom:'lfrtipB',
        language: {
                        lengthMenu: 'Show _MENU_' // Customize the "Show entries" text here
                    },
        buttons:[
            {
            extend: 'csv',
            text:'<i class="fas fa-file-excel">CSV</i>',
            className:'btn btn-secondary',
            titleAttr:'CSV',
            exportOptions: {
                modifier: {
                    search: 'none'
                }
            }
        }
        ],
        // Adjusted dom option
        initComplete: function () {
            var buttons = $('.dt-buttons').addClass('buttons-container');
            $('.dataTables_length').after(buttons);
        },
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you check which part is taking more time ? Did you debug it ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, first all thousands of rows are being loaded and only after the table is formed. So this is causing the delay. I tried to add ajax and serverside: true but no luck. I have modified my initial code withy the changes